# Extending CAShapeLayer with physics attributes (or is there a better solution)?

Tags: cashapelayer

First disclamer, I'm a complete n00b in terms of iOS programming, but have over 15 years of other OOP experience.
I've done extensive search thus far on what I'm trying to accomplish, but have not come up with definitive answer.
I'm trying to create effect of drawing straight lines (simular in effect to fruit ninja cuting motion) where it would draw a line between point a (beginTouch) and b (endTouch) regardless of the angle. 
I was able to achieve it pretty easily with use of CAShapeLayer.  It also very usefull as it supports some animation options that I would like to be able to apply on end result line.
But what I also need is an ability to emulate physics behavior with resulting line shape, such as bouncing, possibly deforming the line to emulate stretching, and apply some sort of destruction animation (fading/breaking appart).
I'm not sure if the CAShapeLayer is the best option to achieve this effect and if it is where do I look next on extending it or combining it with something else.
I know this is not a specific code example type of question, but expert oppinion is appreciate.

Cheers

Alex